# SuperTest / JEST , how to force or mock a 400 status code?

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, supertest

I'm doing unit testing with Jest and SuperTest, and I can't figure out a way to force a route to give throw an error.

I've attached snippets of my code :

```
    const router = require('express').Router();
    const Thoughts = require('../models/thought.model')
    
    router.get('/thoughts', (req,res)=>{
      Thoughts.find().then((thought)=>{
        res.status(200).send({thought})
      }).catch((err)=>{
        res.sendStatus(400).send(err)
      })
    })
```

```
   const normRoutes = require('../routes/normRoutes')
   const request = require('supertest');
   const express = require('express');
   const mongoose = require('mongoose')


    const app = express();

    app.use('/api', normRoutes)

    beforeAll(async () => {
        const url = "MONGO_URL"
        await mongoose.connect(url, {    
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useCreateIndex: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true })
      })


    test('GET /api/thoughts --> 400 if error', () => { 
       ## missing logic to force a 400 
        request(app)
        .get('/api/thoughts)
        .expect(400)
        .done()
    })
```

Comment: The handler implementation is a closed box. It isn't open to inject a mock of 
 the Thoughts model. Although, it's still viable to mock the model at import time. Could you update your question to include the import statement for the Thoughts model?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule I've updated the code

Comment: Your import statement shows a TodoItem model and not Thought.

Comment: Sorry, added the correct import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mock `find` method of `Thought` model to reject with an error in your test.

First, import the model in your test and automock it using jest.

```
const normRoutes = require('../routes/normRoutes')
const request = require('supertest');
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Thoughts = require('../models/thought.model');
# This is hoisted so the previous import it a jest mock.
jest.mock('../models/thought.model');
```

Next, ensure that tests use an actual implementation before running each tests by calling `mockRestore` on the automock.

```
const app = express();

app.use('/api', normRoutes)

beforeAll(async () => {
    const url = "MONGO_URL"
    await mongoose.connect(url, {    
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useCreateIndex: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true })
  })

beforeEach(() => {
  # This restores the mock back to the actual Thoughts model implementation. 
  # This allows for other tests to use the actual implementation.
  # https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockrestore
  Thoughts.mockRestore();
});
```

Finally, mock the implementation of find in the test that should error.

```
test('GET /api/thoughts --> 400 if error', () => { 
   # Thought model find method is mocked to reject with an error.
   Thoughts.mockImplementation(() => ({
     find: jest.fn().mockRejectedValueOnce(
       new Error('Connection Failed or something')
     );
   }));
   
   ## missing logic to force a 400 
    request(app)
    .get('/api/thoughts')
    .expect(400)
    .done();
})
```

Comment: So, and the 400 status?